# SQL Composite Key that keeps on giving me a duplicate error even though only 1 of the composite key is duplicate.

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, duplicates, composite-primary-key

So i have 2 composite keys in my table expertise. However, Whenever i update or insert a new data, it will always show me an error saying "#1062 - Duplicate entry '8-Lawyer' for key 'PRIMARY'" 
I am using phpmyadmin for the database. 
[image]

Comment: no, you're not using "phpmyadmin for the database". phpmyadmin is a MANAGEMENT INTERFACE for the mysql database.

Comment: and you appear have to a unique constraint on the `particulars_id` field

Comment: @MarcB oh.. sorry mybad im still learning. But is there anyways where i can stop having the duplicate error? thanks

Comment: @MarcB I  just added that thnking that it may help. But now i do not know how to remove it. It didnt help either

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like the primary key on the table is **`(Particulars_ID,Expertise)`**, and it appears you are attempting to insert a row with Particulars_ID='8' Expertise='Lawyer' and such a row already exists in the table. The attempt to insert that row is causing MySQL to throw the error, because inserting the row would be a violation of the constraint (which is designed to disallow adding more than one row with the same values). It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve, or how you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: @spencer7593 Yes i have another row with particular_ID  =8 but the Expertise name is different. So it should not have this error.

Comment: @Samuel: The MySQL error is reporting that there is such a row. It's possible that the INSERT statement that is being executed is attempting to insert two rows with those same values. The first row would be inserted, the second would encounter the error, then the entire statement would be rolled back.

Comment: @spencer7593 hmm before i add i do not have a row with the same composite keys. But if the command is really executing twice then what do you suggest i can do? else my code will always have error whenever i want to update this table